# Python Setup.py Build_Ext --inplace

Tags: python, cython, setup.py

I am building a Cython program (called for ex. testpackage) using the command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

In a folder like `/home/USER/Documents/testpackage/`. The build runs successfully but when I cd into another folder, I can no longer use the module `testpackage`. Is there another command I can run instead of `--inplace` so that I can `import testpackage` in Python in any folder? I looked at the `anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` folder and do not see any reference to `testpackage` anywhere. Is this standard for Cython builds?

NOTE: I am doing this through a .sh file using `conda build testpackage` so the command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` is actually in the shell file.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 26):

The --inplace option creates the shared object file (with .so suffix) in the current directory. To use this module from python this file must be in the python path (sys.path).

To install to the system python folder run

```
python setup.py build_ext
sudo python setup.py install
```

If you don't have admin rights, you can also install locally using

```
python setup.py build_ext
python setup.py install --user
```